# Calculate difference of two shapes two form new shape (boolean algebra)

Tags: android, imageview, drawable

Look at the example pictures provided. What I am trying to achieve is to cut out a random form (in the example a semi circle) from a card view background (or any other image for that matter).

So that in the end I have the background image with the cutout shape. The final result would be picture three where there is transparancy around the action button.

Notes:

- Elevation and Shadows shall not get lost
- I do not want to use a static background so it has to be a real cutout and not a overlay with background color as in the examples
- UI has to adjust and resize dynamically - so does the cutout

How to achieve this?

[image: Without cutout]

[image: With cutout]

[image: With transparency]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This semi-circle cutout can be achieved using a `MaterialShapeDrawable` with a custom `ShapeAppearanceModel`. This cut-out is a similar behaviour used in `BottomAppBar` which has this semi circle into its Top Edge side. The `BottomAppBar` uses a [BottomAppBarTopEdgeTreatment](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomappbar/BottomAppBarTopEdgeTreatment) in its `ShapeAppearanceModel` for the Top side only. What you need is a similar behaviour but instead of Top Edge side to be on the Bottom Edge side.

In the below example i have used the same code used in [BottomAppBarTopEdgeTreatment](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/bottomappbar/BottomAppBarTopEdgeTreatment.java) with the only difference that you can move the semi-circle to a specific x position using the `cutoutEndSpacingDp` used in the constructor of `CutoutCircleEdgeTreatment`.

1.Get the latest Material Design Library (`'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'`) and add it into your grandle depedencies.

2.Create a subclass of `EdgeTreatment` with name `CutoutCircleEdgeTreatment` like below:

```
public class CutoutCircleEdgeTreatment extends EdgeTreatment {

    private static final int ARC_QUARTER = 90;
    private static final int ARC_HALF = 180;
    private static final int ANGLE_UP = 270;
    private static final int ANGLE_LEFT = 180;
    private static final float ROUNDED_CORNER_FAB_OFFSET = 1.75f;

    private float roundedCornerRadius;
    private float fabMargin;
    private float fabDiameter;
    private float cradleVerticalOffset;
    private float horizontalOffset;
    private float fabCornerSize = -1f;
    private float cutoutEndSpacing = 0;

    public CutoutCircleEdgeTreatment(Resources res, float fabDiameterDp, float cutoutEndSpacingDp){

        fabMargin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 0, res.getDisplayMetrics());
        roundedCornerRadius = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 0, res.getDisplayMetrics());
        cradleVerticalOffset = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 0, res.getDisplayMetrics());
        fabDiameter = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, fabDiameterDp, res.getDisplayMetrics());
        cutoutEndSpacing = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, cutoutEndSpacingDp, res.getDisplayMetrics());
    }

    @Override
    public void getEdgePath(float length, float center, float interpolation, @NonNull ShapePath shapePath) {

        horizontalOffset = -center + ((fabMargin * 2 + fabDiameter)/2) + cutoutEndSpacing;

        //below is the same code used in BottomAppBarTopEdgeTreatment getEdgePath()
        if (fabDiameter == 0) {
            // There is no cutout to draw.
            shapePath.lineTo(length, 0);
            return;
        }

        float cradleDiameter = fabMargin * 2 + fabDiameter;
        float cradleRadius = cradleDiameter / 2f;
        float roundedCornerOffset = interpolation * roundedCornerRadius;
        float middle = center + horizontalOffset;

        // The center offset of the cutout tweens between the vertical offset when attached, and the
        // cradleRadius as it becomes detached.
        float verticalOffset =
                interpolation * cradleVerticalOffset + (1 - interpolation) * cradleRadius;
        float verticalOffsetRatio = verticalOffset / cradleRadius;
        if (verticalOffsetRatio >= 1.0f) {
            // Vertical offset is so high that there's no curve to draw in the edge, i.e., the fab is
            // actually above the edge so just draw a straight line.
            shapePath.lineTo(length, 0);
            return; // Early exit.
        }

        // Calculate the path of the cutout by calculating the location of two adjacent circles. One
        // circle is for the rounded corner. If the rounded corner circle radius is 0 the corner will
        // not be rounded. The other circle is the cutout.

        // Calculate the X distance between the center of the two adjacent circles using pythagorean
        // theorem.
        float cornerSize = fabCornerSize * interpolation;
        boolean useCircleCutout = fabCornerSize == -1 || java.lang.Math.abs(fabCornerSize * 2f - fabDiameter) < .1f;
        float arcOffset = 0;
        if (!useCircleCutout) {
            verticalOffset = 0;
            arcOffset = ROUNDED_CORNER_FAB_OFFSET;
        }

        float distanceBetweenCenters = cradleRadius + roundedCornerOffset;
        float distanceBetweenCentersSquared = distanceBetweenCenters * distanceBetweenCenters;
        float distanceY = verticalOffset + roundedCornerOffset;
        float distanceX = (float) Math.sqrt(distanceBetweenCentersSquared - (distanceY * distanceY));

        // Calculate the x position of the rounded corner circles.
        float leftRoundedCornerCircleX = middle - distanceX;
        float rightRoundedCornerCircleX = middle + distanceX;

        // Calculate the arc between the center of the two circles.
        float cornerRadiusArcLength = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(distanceX / distanceY));
        float cutoutArcOffset = (ARC_QUARTER - cornerRadiusArcLength) + arcOffset;

        // Draw the starting line up to the left rounded corner.
        shapePath.lineTo(/* x= */ leftRoundedCornerCircleX, /* y= */ 0);

        // Draw the arc for the left rounded corner circle. The bounding box is the area around the
        // circle's center which is at `(leftRoundedCornerCircleX, roundedCornerOffset)`.
        shapePath.addArc(
                /* left= */ leftRoundedCornerCircleX - roundedCornerOffset,
                /* top= */ 0,
                /* right= */ leftRoundedCornerCircleX + roundedCornerOffset,
                /* bottom= */ roundedCornerOffset * 2,
                /* startAngle= */ ANGLE_UP,
                /* sweepAngle= */ cornerRadiusArcLength);

        if (useCircleCutout) {
            // Draw the cutout circle.
            shapePath.addArc(
                    /* left= */ middle - cradleRadius,
                    /* top= */ -cradleRadius - verticalOffset,
                    /* right= */ middle + cradleRadius,
                    /* bottom= */ cradleRadius - verticalOffset,
                    /* startAngle= */ ANGLE_LEFT - cutoutArcOffset,
                    /* sweepAngle= */ cutoutArcOffset * 2 - ARC_HALF);
        } else {
            float cutoutDiameter = fabMargin + cornerSize * 2f;
            shapePath.addArc(
                    /* left= */ middle - cradleRadius,
                    /* top= */ -(cornerSize + fabMargin),
                    /* right= */ middle - cradleRadius + cutoutDiameter,
                    /* bottom= */ (fabMargin + cornerSize),
                    /* startAngle= */ ANGLE_LEFT - cutoutArcOffset,
                    /* sweepAngle= */ (cutoutArcOffset * 2 - ARC_HALF) / 2f);

            shapePath.lineTo(middle + cradleRadius - (cornerSize + fabMargin / 2f), /* y= */
                    (cornerSize + fabMargin));

            shapePath.addArc(
                    /* left= */ middle + cradleRadius - (cornerSize * 2f + fabMargin),
                    /* top= */  -(cornerSize + fabMargin),
                    /* right= */ middle + cradleRadius,
                    /* bottom= */ (fabMargin + cornerSize),
                    /* startAngle= */ 90,
                    /* sweepAngle= */ -90 + cutoutArcOffset);
        }

        // Draw an arc for the right rounded corner circle. The bounding box is the area around the
        // circle's center which is at `(rightRoundedCornerCircleX, roundedCornerOffset)`.
        shapePath.addArc(
                /* left= */ rightRoundedCornerCircleX - roundedCornerOffset,
                /* top= */ 0,
                /* right= */ rightRoundedCornerCircleX + roundedCornerOffset,
                /* bottom= */ roundedCornerOffset * 2,
                /* startAngle= */ ANGLE_UP - cornerRadiusArcLength,
                /* sweepAngle= */ cornerRadiusArcLength);

        // Draw the ending line after the right rounded corner.
        shapePath.lineTo(/* x= */ length, /* y= */ 0);
    }
}
```

From the constructor above you can pass the `fabDiameterDp` which is the circle diameter in dps and the `cutoutEndSpacingDp` which is the end spacing in dps needed to move the semi-circle to a specific x position from the end. Of course you can make any other modifications you want based on your needs.

3.You can use the above `CutoutCircleEdgeTreatment` like below:

**For Material Components like MaterialCardView etc. which they have already a MaterialShapeDrawable as a background:**

```
MaterialCardView materialCardView = findViewById(R.id.materialCardView);
materialCardView.setShapeAppearanceModel(materialCardView.getShapeAppearanceModel()
        .toBuilder()
        .setBottomEdge(new CutoutCircleEdgeTreatment(getResources(), 80, 20))
        .build());
```

Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#81afdc"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/materialCardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-35dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        app:elevation="3dp"
        app:fabCustomSize="70dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/materialCardView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/materialCardView"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        app:tint="@android:color/white" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**For Non-Material Components like ConstraintLayout, RelativeLayout etc. which they don't have a MaterialShapeDrawable:**

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
ShapeAppearanceModel shapeAppearanceModel = new ShapeAppearanceModel()
        .toBuilder()
        .setBottomEdge(new CutoutCircleEdgeTreatment(getResources(), 80, 20))
        .build();
MaterialShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new MaterialShapeDrawable(shapeAppearanceModel);
shapeDrawable.setFillColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this, android.R.color.white));
ViewCompat.setBackground(relativeLayout, shapeDrawable);
```

Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#81afdc"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-35dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        app:elevation="3dp"
        app:fabCustomSize="70dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        app:tint="@android:color/white" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Result:**

[image: cutout_semicircle]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Also I did not expect that this will be such a complex task to achieve. I expected some blend mode via XML. I think the framework has to consider this in the future. But ya it works great